# Using g.applyLayout in controller breaks unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I've got a controller method that needs to return a JSON map, one of the items inside of which is html from a template.  I'm using code like

```
map['html'] = g.applyLayout(name: 'layoutName', g.render(template: 'template', model: [...])
...
render(map as JSON)
```

And I've got at Controller unit test that calls this method.  However when I run the test, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot return Sitemesh factory it has not been set!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:384)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.FactoryHolder.getFactory(FactoryHolder.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.FactoryHolder$getFactory.call(Unknown Source)
...
```

If I take out the g.applyLayout() and just use the g.render() the test runs.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Here's my unit test class

```
@TestFor(ContactsController)
@Mock([Contact, User, Company])
class ContactsControllerTests {
    @Test
    void testSaveContact() {
        defineBeans {
            contactsManagerService(ContactsManagerService)
        }

        Company company = new Company(name: 'COMPANY 1')
        company.save(validate: false)
        Contact userContact = new Contact(name: 'user contact', email: 'foo@bar.com')
        Contact companyContact = new Contact(name: 'company contact', email: 'foo2@bar.com')
        userContact.save(validate: false)
        companyContact.save(validate: false)
        new User(name: 'user 1', password: 'foo', contact: userContact, company: company).save(validate: false, deepValidate: false)

        controller.params.name = ''
        controller.params.email = 'updated1@bar.com'
        controller.saveContact(userContact.id)
        assertNotNull(response.json.errors) // Name cannot be empty

        response.reset()
        controller.params.name = 'Updated Name'
        controller.params.email = 'updated1@bar.com'
        controller.saveContact(userContact.id)
        assertTrue(response.json.success)

        Contact contact = Contact.read(userContact.id)
        assertEquals('Updated Name', contact.name)
        assertEquals('foo@bar.com', contact.email)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your complete unit test class?

Comment: Updated the question to include the unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing [Jeff's response](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spock-How-to-render-a-view-inside-a-unit-test-td4639793.html#a4639798) in another topic in the mail list I think that you cannot use SiteMesh dependent tags in unit tests.

Possible solutions are:

- Mock your html, asserting that the generated JSON is correct;
- Do an Integration Test to validate your layout and template, since in integration you have access to the full env.;

Comment: Can I mock the call to applyLayout() somehow?

Comment: I figure out how to mock the calls I did this

 `def applyLayoutMock = mockFor(RenderTagLib, true)
        applyLayoutMock.demand.applyLayout { attrs, body -> return 'applied layout' }
        applyLayoutMock.demand.render { template, model -> return 'template rendered' }
        controller.metaClass.g = applyLayoutMock.createMock()` which seems to work for me.

Comment: If you need to mock applyLayout without a controller (such as a service that sends email), you need to use an integration test and you need to metaclass the renderTagLib (Sitemesh doesn't work in Integration tests either).

`def renderTagLib = ApplicationContextHolder.getBean(RenderTagLib)
        renderTagLib.applyLayout = {attrs, body ->
            return body
        }`

Comment: @Zachary Cheers, works great. But in my test I needed to check that the body of the `applyLayout` does not fail, so I changed your code just a tad (added parentheses after the `body` and replaced the `ApplicationContextHolder`, which is now deprecated). This is what I ended up having: `def renderTagLib = Holders.applicationContext.getBean(RenderTagLib); renderTagLib.applyLayout = { attrs, body -> return body() }`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm going through and changing the tests in our project to execute the body to make sure it isn't failing.

Comment: ApplicationContextHolder doesn't seem to be there anymore so I added a `GrailsApplication` injection to my Integration Test and did the following
`def renderTagLib = grailsApplication.getMainContext().getBean(RenderTagLib)`
`renderTagLib.applyLayout = {attrs, body -> return body }`